# How to display only subscribed posts in Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

So there is 2 apps in Python, one is for blog posts and second is for user profile. I want to display on my HTML  main page only user's subscribed posts.

```
blog post models.py

class News(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='user_news',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=250
    )
    description = RichTextField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        updating = self.pk is not None
```

```
blog post views.py

def home(request):
    blogs= Blog.objects.order_by('-created_date')
    users = User.objects.order_by('-date_joined')

    context = {
        "blogs": blogs,
        'users': users,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

```
user profile models.py

class User(AbstractUser):

    followers = models.ManyToManyField("Follow")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class Follow(models.Model):
    followed = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='user_followers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    followed_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='user_follows',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.followed_by.username} started following {self.followed.username}"
```

```
user profile views.py

def follow_or_unfollow_user(request, user_id):
    followed = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
    followed_by = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)

    follow, created = Follow.objects.get_or_create(
        followed=followed,
        followed_by=followed_by
    )

    if created:
        followed.followers.add(follow)

    else:
        followed.followers.remove(follow)
        follow.delete()

    return redirect("view_user_information", username=followed.username)
```

what i did and it did not show posts of subscribed accounts

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
        {% for blog in account.user_blogs.all %}
        {% for blog in blogs|slice:"2" %}
        
        <div
          
          class="swiper-slide subscription-card"
        >
        <a href="{% url 'news_details' new.slug %}">
          <div class="subscription-card__header">
            <div>
              <h5>{{blog.user.first_name}} {{blog.user.last_name}}</h5>
              <span>{{blog.created_date}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="subscription-card__body">
            <img
              src="{{blog.banner.url}}"
              alt=""
            />
            <h5>{{blog.title|truncatechars:30}}</h5>
          </div>
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
```

`{% for blog in blogs|slice:"2" %}` this works perfect but I want something like
`{% for blog in account.followers.user_blogs.all %}` so that it will display only followers blogs

Answer (score 0):

You can write simply like:

```
def home(request):
     #this query to get all follows from your News model's users
     followers_blog = get_object_or_404(News, name=request.user)

     context = {
       "followers_blog":followers_blog
     }
     return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: banner, category, category_id, description, id, slug, tags, title, user, user_id. So I wrote "followers_blog = get_object_or_404(News, user=request.user)" and now I am getting "get() returned more than one Blogs -- it returned 3!"

Comment: followers_blog = get_object_or_404(News, user=request.user)

Comment: followers_blog = get_object_or_404(News, user=request.user) // this line of code gave me account blogs, not followers. it displays own blog posts not followers

Comment: and if there is more than 1 post it gave me  "get() returned more than one Blogs -- it returned 3!"